# Matlab: neural network time series prediction?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, prediction

**Background:** I am trying to use MATLAB's Neural Network toolbox to predict future values of data.  I run it from the GUI, but I have also included the output code below.

**Problem:** My predicted values lag behind the actual values by 2 time periods, and I do not know how to actually see a "t+1" (predicted) value.

**Code:**

```
% Solve an Autoregression Time-Series Problem with a NAR Neural Network
% Script generated by NTSTOOL
% Created Tue Mar 05 22:09:39 EST 2013
%
% This script assumes this variable is defined:
%
%   close_data - feedback time series.

targetSeries = tonndata(close_data_short,false,false);

% Create a Nonlinear Autoregressive Network
feedbackDelays = 1:3;
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = narnet(feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize);

% Choose Feedback Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% Settings for feedback input are automatically applied to feedback output
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

% Prepare the Data for Training and Simulation
% The function PREPARETS prepares timeseries data for a particular network,
% shifting time by the minimum amount to fill input states and layer states.
% Using PREPARETS allows you to keep your original time series data unchanged, while
% easily customizing it for networks with differing numbers of delays, with
% open loop or closed loop feedback modes.
[inputs,inputStates,layerStates,targets] = preparets(net,{},{},targetSeries);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'time';  % Divide up every value
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Choose a Training Function
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean squared error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','plotresponse', ...
  'ploterrcorr', 'plotinerrcorr'};


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets,inputStates,layerStates);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs,inputStates,layerStates);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = gmultiply(targets,tr.trainMask);
valTargets = gmultiply(targets,tr.valMask);
testTargets = gmultiply(targets,tr.testMask);
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotresponse(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrcorr(errors)
%figure, plotinerrcorr(inputs,errors)

% Closed Loop Network
% Use this network to do multi-step prediction.
% The function CLOSELOOP replaces the feedback input with a direct
% connection from the outout layer.
netc = closeloop(net);
[xc,xic,aic,tc] = preparets(netc,{},{},targetSeries);
yc = netc(xc,xic,aic);
perfc = perform(net,tc,yc)

% Early Prediction Network
% For some applications it helps to get the prediction a timestep early.
% The original network returns predicted y(t+1) at the same time it is given y(t+1).
% For some applications such as decision making, it would help to have predicted
% y(t+1) once y(t) is available, but before the actual y(t+1) occurs.
% The network can be made to return its output a timestep early by removing one delay
% so that its minimal tap delay is now 0 instead of 1.  The new network returns the
% same outputs as the original network, but outputs are shifted left one timestep.
nets = removedelay(net);
[xs,xis,ais,ts] = preparets(nets,{},{},targetSeries);
ys = nets(xs,xis,ais);
closedLoopPerformance = perform(net,tc,yc)
```

**Proposed Solution:** I believe the answer lies in the last part of the code "Early Prediction Network".  I'm just not sure how to remove 'one delay'.

**Additional question:** Is there a function that can be output from this so I can use it over and over? Or would I just have to keep retraining once I get the next time period of data?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the code? If your time series is non stationary, you may be having the impression the output is lagged!

Comment: It is a dynamic time series, yes.  I would like to predict the next value in the sequence. Can I do that with a nonlinear autoregressive (NAR) neural network?

Comment: The main assumption for a NAR is that the data is stationary - i.e. the mean and and varaince are constant over time.  An example of stationary data would be a sine wave, yes? My data is random and it varies nonlinearly and nonstationary.  What would you recommend for trying to predict this?

Comment: Possibly an ARIMA model, or some type of fuzzy logic?

Comment: I believe that you should work in steps: (1) see if the data is stationary; (2) if not, deal with it (for instance, differentiate the data); (3) test the most possible model, for instance, ar model; (4) try nonlinear model, for instance, nar; (5) go to a nn model.

Comment: Ok I will try that logic. My problem is trying to use a NAR or NARX and change to the closed-loop. Then use this to predict N periods into the future.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I am working with NAR time-series tool and I have the same code as the OP. I have stationary data. Also, I am using `feedbackDelays = 1:7` . I want to predict future 10 values , but I do not know how to do it, any help .

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but NAR net just has a single input which is to be predicted then what do we have to write in "inputs" and "targets"?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that this question does not remain open whilst the answer is already present I will post the comment that seems to address the issue:

Credits to @DanielTheRocketMan

> I believe that you should work in steps:
>
> 1. see if the data is stationary
> 2. if not, deal with it (for instance, differentiate the data)
> 3. test the most possible model, for instance, ar model
> 4. try nonlinear model, for instance, nar
> 5. go to a nn model.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler version. I have tested this code and this code works fine for me.

```
inputs = X;  %define input and target
targets = y;

hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

%   Set up Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

outputss(x,:) = net(inputs);

errors = gsubtract(targets,outputss);
mse(errors)
```